# Align image center with bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, alignment

Currently I have:

```
<div id="">
    <input type="text" class="span2 pull-left" value="">
    <i class="icon"></i>
    <input type="text" class="span2 pull-right" value="">
</div>
```

I want to have one input on the left, one on the right and the image dead center. How can i center the image and still be aligned horizontal.

I have tried to wrap the image inside av div, p and use .pagination-centered, .pagination-center. Its works okei, but breaks the horizontal.

At the moment im just using a absolute position with left= 50%, That looks great my on my tab and computer, but not my phone.

Any tips now how to get this working?

Comment: you know there is a class called `row` right ?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking [this](http://bootply.com/80727)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                           <input type="text" class"span2 pull-left" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class"span2 pull-right" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats for versions >= 3

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"><input type="text" value=""></div>
      <div class="span4"><img alt="300x300" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" class="img-responsive"></div>
      <div class="span4"><input type="text" value=""></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might want to try using this code for version number 2    [This](http://bootply.com/80735)

Comment: I didnt know about the row class. I'm just editing a template to a program im using. Thanks for the help. I'll check it out when i get home from work.